# How can I handle "-10005, 'IPC timeout'" error during python connection to MetaTrader5?

Tags: python, metatrader5

I have tried to write this code to initialize MetaTrader5 from python:

```
import MetaTrader5 as mt5
 
# establish connection to the MetaTrader 5 terminal
if not mt5.initialize(login=999999, server="myserver-Demo",password="abcdefg"):
    print("failed to connect at account #{}, error code: {}".format(account, mt5.last_error()))
    mt5.shutdown()
```

But this code returns:

```
failed to connect at account #999999, error code: (-10005, 'IPC timeout')
```

What should I do?

Comment: Hi there.  Did you ever find an answer to this?  I'm having the same problem -- well, very similar.  I'm getting the -10005 error without even trying to connect to a broker account.  just mt5.initialize() gives me the error.  Did you ever figure out what your issue was and/or a solution?

Comment: Hi David,
This worked for me:
`if not mt5.initialize(path=path, user = account, server= server, password=password):`

Comment: Hi V.Nouri  thanks for the response.  That doesn't seem to be working for me either.  Although this entire "-10005, 'IPC timeout'" error seems to be very intermittent. Doesn't happen much but when it happens it sticks for a while (an hour... maybe hours).  Very weird.  And no googling finds any answers. I believe IPC is interprocess communication, but that doesn't tell us the cause.  So I think it's some kind of internal mt5 error that they're not documenting.

Comment: Hi David,
Can you put your code here and mention where this error occurs?
Because I cannot exactly remember how I handled this issue.

Comment: Check this link too: https://www.mql5.com/en/forum/332609